# How to create a REGex for this ---> 7 to 12 characters long, with the 4th, 6th and (if it exists) the 10th being one of these: 1, 5, 9, A, S, K

Tags: regex

I want to validate a business firewall using this --> 7 to 12 characters long, with the 4th, 6th and (if it exists) the 10th being one of these:  1, 5, 9, A, S, K

^[a-zA-Z0-9]{7-12}$

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex,

```
^.{3}[159ASK].[159ASK].(?:..[159ASK].{0,2}|.{0,2})$
```

The string beginning with `^` then allows any three characters with `.{3}` then as you wanted, 4th character is anyone among `[159ASK]` then `.` represents any character as 5th character then sixth character again is represented by `[159ASK]` then `.` allows any character as seventh character and finally `(?:..[159ASK].{0,2}|.{0,2})` this represents either any of two characters or if they are at least 10 characters then 10th character is again from `[159ASK]`

Comment: [What if the input is 8 characters long?](https://regex101.com/r/B1Synx/1)

Comment: @Potatoツ: Good catch. Let me update :)

Comment: Much better now. :)

Comment: @Potatoツ: Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the solution provided by @Pushpesh but in case you further want to decrease the length of solution then you can use

```
^.{3}([159ASK].)\1(?:..\1{0,2}|.{0,2})$
```

where **\1** is a back reference which represents the value of first capturing group that is **[159ASK].** .

**?:** represents non capturing group

you can read further

[Capturing/Non Capturing Group and Back Reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)